# How to plot a probability map in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am not that much expert in python, still learning.

I have a probability map (values between range 0 and 1) 'prop' saved in `np.array` with the shape `(3, 256, 256)`,

that `prob(0,256,256)` is the probability of each pixel belonging to `class 0` , `prob(1,256,256)` for `class 1` and `prob(2,256,256)` for `class 2`.

I tried to plot this:

```
plt.imshow(prob[1,:,:])
plt.show()
```

but the output is a black image, I do not see any output.
I wanted to plot the image of each class separately. If I am not mistaken this is called `heatmap`. Could someone please guide me with this? I do not know how to visualize this array.

Comment: The way you describe your approach sounds correct. SO I guess the problem of the blank image lies somewhere else in the code that you don't show here. As usual, stick to [ask] and provide a [mcve] of the issue, such that people are able to actually help you.

Comment: What are `prob.dtype`, `prob[1].min()` and `prob[1].max()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull out `class 0`, call `prob[0]`. For any `class i`, then `prob[i]`.

To plot three distinct heat maps, use `subplot`:

```
plt.figure(1)
for i in range(3):
        plt.subplot(1,3,i+1)
        plt.imshow(prob[i], cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is showing black image for all of them :(

Comment: Yes that is because **`prob[0]` is the same as `prob[0,:,:]`**. You cannot expect that the code behaves differently when using either of the two. Either it works or it fails for both.

Comment: Is your data loaded correctly? Can you try `print(prob[0])` to verify the array is holding non-zero values?

Comment: Also, do you have the line `plt.figure(1)` or similar in your code? (Updated my answer to reflect that need)

Comment: @Daniel You don't need `plt.figure(1)`. It doesn't hurt, but it's also not necessary.